# How to configure the base class for 'Example' generated by mybatis generator plug-in

Tags: java, mybatis

How to configure the base class for "Example" generated by the mybatis generator plug-in, or can the generator plug-in configure the base class for "Example"?

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible with a custom [plugin](http://www.mybatis.org/generator/reference/pluggingIn.html).

If extending the base class is all you need, it is easy.

```java
package mygroup.myplugin;

import java.util.List;

import org.mybatis.generator.api.IntrospectedTable;
import org.mybatis.generator.api.PluginAdapter;
import org.mybatis.generator.api.dom.java.FullyQualifiedJavaType;
import org.mybatis.generator.api.dom.java.TopLevelClass;

public class ExampleSuperclassPlugin extends PluginAdapter {
  @Override
  public boolean validate(List<String> warnings) {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean modelExampleClassGenerated(
      TopLevelClass topLevelClass, IntrospectedTable introspectedTable) {
    // Add import
    topLevelClass.addImportedType(new FullyQualifiedJavaType("your.pkg.ExampleBase"));
    // Add 'extends ExampleBase'
    topLevelClass.setSuperClass("ExampleBase");
    return true;
  }
}
```

In `generatorConfig.xml`, add `<plugin />` entry.

```xml
<generatorConfiguration>
  ...
  <context ...>
    <plugin type="mygroup.myplugin.ExampleSuperclassPlugin" />
    ...
```

Make sure that the custom plugin JAR is included in the classpath when running Generator.
If you use Generator Maven Plugin, for example, add it as a dependency to the plugin in `pom.xml`.

```xml
<build>
  ...
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.mybatis.generator</groupId>
      <artifactId>mybatis-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.7</version>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
          <artifactId>myplugin</artifactId>
          <version>0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        ...
```